# Defining the Problem Hamiltonian for Quantum Annealing in Solving the Shortest Path Problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, optimization

I’m currently studying quantum annealing and its application to solving the shortest path problem. However, I’m facing challenges in defining the problem Hamiltonian, whose ground state should encode the solution to this specific optimization problem.

Setup: Given a graph (G = (V, E)) with a set of vertices (V) and edges (E), and an adjacency matrix A, in which each entry $A_{ij}$ indicates the weight of the edge between vertices i and j.
So far, I have introduced a binary variable $z_i$ where $z_i = 1$ if $i$ is part of the path, and $z_i = 0$ otherwise. Thus, the state of our system is represented by the vector $|z_1, \dots, z_{|V|}>$.

Problem: **The goal is to construct a problem Hamiltonian $H_P$, whose ground state should correspond to the shortest path through the graph G, from a starting vertex $s$ to a final vertex $t$.**

Ideas: The first step in defining $H_P$ if to define the objective function $h$ that quantifies the cost of a given path. For the shortest path problem, this could be the sum of edge weights along the path $H_C= \sum_{i \in V}{A_{ij}z_i z_j}$.

The next step should be to include the constraints of the problem in our Hamiltonian. I think these should be:

1. The path should start at node s and end at node t.
2. The path should be continuous, so every edge in the path should exist (perhaps this could be seen as every node on the path other than $s$ and $t$ should have exactly 2 connected nodes).

I've looked into existing papers, and found similar reasoning/ results, but I am having trouble defining the exact Hamiltonian corresponding to my problem. Here are some of the references:

- Krauss, Thomas & McCollum, Joey. (2020). Solving the Network Shortest Path Problem on a Quantum Annealer. IEEE Transactions on Quantum Engineering. 1. 1-12. 10.1109/TQE.2020.3021921.
- Bauckhage, Christian & Brito, Eduardo & Cvejoski, Kostadin & Ojeda, César & Schücker, Jannis & Sifa, Rafet. (2018). Towards Shortest Paths Via Adiabatic Quantum Computing.
- Lucas, Andrew. (2014). Ising formulations of many NP problems. Frontiers in Physics (Traveling Salesman in Particular). 2. 5. 10.3389/fphy.2014.00005.

Any help in defining $H_P$ would be greatly appreciated!